# I broke my mobile, help me

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, unrooting

I rooted my android KitKat recently and most of bloatware permanently. Today my phone was causing some problems. It showed Service exchange error, play store won't open, accounts won't sync, since i deleted my phone app as well and realised exDialer was just to improve UI of stock dialer and not a complete standalone dialer. I was angry and angry people can't think much. I removed my root access and factory reseted my mobile. 
Now I realise my swiftkeyboard is also gone and can't type wifi password and I don't have a mobile data plan.

How can I fix my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to flash stock fimrware on it. which phone is it, I will put latest firmware for you so you can flash it.

Comment: http://www.modifyandroid.com/stock-roms/qmobile/how-to-flash-stock-rom-for-qmobile-noir-a290/